# Create object containing a list using Dynamic Linq Core with Entity Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq

I have the following two classes:

```
public Part {
    public string PartNumber {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public List<Warehouse> Warehouses {get; set;}
}

public Warehouse {
    public string PartNumber {get; set;}
    public string WarehouseName {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public int ReorderPoint {get; set;}
}
```

Using Entity Framework Core 2.0 I have associated these using a one to many relationship.  Using Dynamic Linq Core I'm trying to create a query that returns the PartNumber, Description, and the list of all associated Warehouses for a particular part where the only property in the Warehouses list is WarehouseName ideally like this:

```
List<string> fields = new List<string> {"PartNumber", "Description", "Warehouses.WarehouseName"};
var _dataSet = dbContext.Parts.Include(x => x.Warehouses);
var data = _dataSet.Where("PartNumber = \"Part1234\"").Select("new (" + String.Join(",", fields) + ")").ToDynamicArray();
```

But I receive this error: "No property or field 'Warehouse' exists in type 'List`1'".  If I do something like this it works fine:

```
var data = _dataSet.Where("PartNumber = \"Part1234\"").Select(x => new Part
{
    PartNumber = x.PartNumber,
    Description = x.Description,
    Warehouses = x.Warehouses.Select(y => new Warehouse { Warehouse = y.Warehouse }).ToList()
}).Single();
```

The problem is that I would like it to be dynamic so that the user can just pass in a list of fields from the Part and Warehouse class that they want to get without having to modify the select to build it for those specific fields.

Comment: Try this as a test in your `fields`: `Warehouses[0].WarehouseName`. If that works then, you need to add the index for the other ones too.

Comment: @CodingYoshi This returns a valid data object, but the WarehouseName is only a single field it isn't a list.  How would I add the index to return all warehouses (there could be 0 to 100)?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to support a subquery on `Warehouses`. I'll copy the relevant steps listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577149/3002584):

1. add the following in `ParseAggregate`:

   ```
   Expression ParseAggregate(Expression instance, Type elementType, string methodName, int errorPos)
   {
      // Change starts here
      var originalIt = it;
      var originalOuterIt = outerIt;
      // Change ends here

      outerIt = it;
      ParameterExpression innerIt = Expression.Parameter(elementType, elementType.Name);
      it = innerIt;
      Expression[] args = ParseArgumentList();

      // Change starts here
      it = originalIt;
      outerIt = originalOuterIt;
      // Change ends here

      ...
   }
   ```
2. Add `Select` and `ToList` into `IEnumerableSignatures`, and a respective condition in `ParseAggregate`:

   ```
   interface IEnumerableSignatures
   {
     ...
     void Select(object selector);
     void ToList();
     ...
   }

   Expression ParseAggregate(Expression instance, Type elementType, string methodName, int errorPos)
   {
      ...
      if (signature.Name == "Min" || 
          signature.Name == "Max" || 
          signature.Name == "Select")
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Finally, Your query would be:

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       // example data
       var warehouses = new List<Warehouse>
       {
           new Warehouse { WarehouseName = "NY1", Quantity = 10 },
           new Warehouse { WarehouseName = "NY2", Quantity = 100 }
       };
       var parts = new List<Part> 
       { 
            new Part { PartNumber = "1", Description = "Hammer", Warehouses = warehouses } 
       };
       // query
       var result =
           parts
           .Select(@"new ( 
              PartNumber,
              Description,
              Warehouses.Select(WarehouseName).ToList() as WarehouseNames
           )");
   }
   ```